# Перенос id_rsa на другую машину

Tags: ssh-key

Имеется приватный и публичный ключ сгенерированный в убунте. Необходимо перенести их на другую машину под Windows. Вопрос: какие клиенты проще всего использовать на виндовой машине и как эти ключи вообще заставить работать.

Comment: А для каких целей? Это же виндовс, тут нужно знать, что куда и **для какой программы** копировать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю речь идет о клиенте?

Так как SSH-сервер для окон есть, на базе openssh, даже работает, но вещь все равно загадочная (но думаю ассинхронную авторизацию тоже должен поддерживать).

Я очень люблю и рекоменудю PuTTY, хотя наверно есть и другие.

Такую авторизацию я на ней настраивал. Вот [тут](http://www.pentarh.com/wp/2008/07/21/ssh-public-key-authentication/) - что-то достаточно похожее. Их ppk - это обычный файл приватного ключа.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Смутил вид ключей, которые кушает путти.